# How to sort a list of keyvaluepairs with some operations involved

Tags: c#, list, algorithm, sorting, key-value

As much as there are similar questions here in stack overflow, there is just something about this problem that my solution won't work. I have a given number,

For example: `int target = 15`

Then a list of keyvaluepairs,

```
var farm = new List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>()
{
   new KeyValuePair<string,int>("apple", 25),
   new KeyValuePair<string,int>("veges", 35),
   new KeyValuePair<string,int>("watermelon", 0),
   new KeyValuePair<string,int>("grapes", 10),
}
```

Now I want to sort the list based on the difference of the given number which is 15 and the second element in the list of pairs.

Here's my solution so far but it didn't make any changes:

```
farm.Sort((prod1, prod2) => Math.Abs(prod1.Value - target) < Math.Abs(prod2 - target) 
                                   ? prod1.Value : prod2.Value)
```

Expected sort should be:

```
("grapes", 10)      // |10-15| = 5
("apple", 25)       // |25-15| = 10
("watermelon", 0)  // |0-15| = 15
("veges", 35)       // |35-15| = 20
```

Any insight would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Show the intended output. Also note "*it doesn't work*" is not a technical description of a problem, we cant read your mind

Comment: @TheGeneral Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overload of `List<T>.Sort` you are using accepts the delegate `Comparison<T>`.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1), for arguments `x` and `y`, the return value indicates the following:

| Value | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| Less than 0 | `x` is less than `y` |
| 0 | `x` equals `y` |
| Greater than 0 | `x` is greater than `y` |

Currently you are simply returning the `Value` property of the lesser argument, which has no relevance to the above criteria.

You are also not accounting for the scenario where `prod1` and `prod2` are equal.

The simplest solution is to subtract one from the other:

```
farm.Sort(
    (prod1, prod2) => Math.Abs(prod1.Value - target) - Math.Abs(prod2 - target));
```

Or you could use [`int.CompareTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.compareto) which does the same:

```
farm.Sort(
    (prod1, prod2) => Math.Abs(prod1.Value - target)
        .CompareTo(Math.Abs(prod2 - target)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
        int target = 15;
        var farm = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("apple", 25),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("veges", 30),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("watermelon", 35),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("grapes", 10),
        };
        farm.Sort((prod1, prod2) => Math.Abs(prod1.Value - target).CompareTo(Math.Abs(prod2.Value - target)));
```